# Rotate all but one table header

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rotating

I want to rotate all table headers, except the one to the top left. The attached MWE does the job, but there is some space there that is caused by the one header that is not rotated. How can I avoid this space and make the rotated headers align left, close to the `\midrule` bar?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*{\leftspecialcell}[2][t]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbr]\centering
\caption{Some caption}
\label{somelabel}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
\leftspecialcell{Type of\\heat exchanger} &     \rot{\leftspecialcell{Adjacent\\ducts}}  \\ 
\midrule
Heat wheel              &   A \\    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to align the first header at the `[b]`ase:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*{\leftspecialcell}[2][t]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Some caption}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c}
    \toprule
    \leftspecialcell[b]{Type of\\heat exchanger} & \rot{\leftspecialcell{Adjacent\\ducts}} \\
    \midrule
    Heat wheel              &   A \\    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution based on `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in cells,  and `rotating`. Added the `caption` package for a better vertical spacing between caption and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, rotating, caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lb}
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\theadfont Adjacent}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Some caption}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c}
    \toprule
    \thead{Type of & \\heat exchanger} & \rothead{Adjacent\\ducts} \\
    \midrule
    Heat wheel & A \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]